# enforce identical scale between two objects saved in .png files

Tags: gimp, resize

I have two characters like this:
[image]

But the *white* ones and the *black* ones are stored in different files, and the relative size of them, the scale of the object, although it has the same shape, is different.

Is there a way, using gimp, to enforce that they are the same size?

Comment: Can you just make the 2 documents have the same image height? Then adjust the objects size to fit within the document. Or place both images into the same document to compare sizes.

Comment: I don't really get what the problem is. What have you tried?